# Passing userdata to array_walk and reference to self

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to filter multidimensional array by searched keyword.

I'm using `array_walk` but i couldnt send searched keyword inside to `array_walk` in `class`

#### multidimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [plugin_name] => Custom Extension
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [plugin_name] => Hello World
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [plugin_name] => Test Plugin
        )

)
```

I tried following functions:

#### First one

```
array_walk($lists, function(&$value, $index){
    if (stripos($value->plugin_name, $this->search) === false)
        unset($lists[$index]);
});
```

This gives me `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in`

#### Second one

```
$search = $this->search;
array_walk($lists, function(&$value, $index){
    if (stripos($value->plugin_name, $search) === false)
        unset($lists[$index]);
});
```

I couldn't get `$search` var from `array_walk function`

#### Third one

```
$search = $this->search;
array_walk($lists, function (&$value, $index) use ($search) {
if (stripos($value->plugin_name, $search) !== false)
    return $value;
});
```

`$search` passed successfully with `use` keyword but `$lists` array didnt change so not referenced. Why?

What should I do or use another function instead of `array_walk`?

## Solution

```
$params = array('search' => $this->search, 'data' => $lists);

array_walk($lists, function (&$value, $index) use (&$params) {
if (stripos($value->plugin_name, $params['search']) === false)
  unset($params['data'][$index]);
});

$lists = $params['data'];
```

I sent params with `use` keyword as array and reference to self.

Comment: I think `array_filter` will make more sense in your case. Also `stristr` will make  case-insensitive search might be better than `strpos`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `use` keyword.

```
array_walk($lists, function (&$value, $index) use ($search) {
```

PHP is not like JavaScript, so the anonymous function is still in a different scope, but that is what `use` is for.  I would link to the documentation on `use`, but there does not seem to be any.

Comment: Thank you so much. `$search` var successfully passed but didnt referenced. Updated question with `Third one`

Comment: Updated question with solution, thanks for help with `use` keyword

Comment: This is php hack, this use of `use` keyword is undocumented and this solution can only be used with anonymous function.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php 
There's no guarantee that it will work or be broken in future releases of PHP as its not officially supported.Its simply a complex way of doing same thing as what using `global` keyword does e.g. `global $search;` inside function - which is not a great practice.

Comment: @RomanToasov are you sure? This is documented: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-160